# Attaching a File while sending mail in COBOL

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have a COBOL batch program where I am able to send mail notification to an ID once my job is complete however, I also want to add an attachment in the mail of the processed file.

The following code attaches another mail as an attachment.

```
HELO SANTAANA
MAIL FROM:<abc@somting.com>
RCPT TO:<abc@something.com>
DATA
From: LandT P2P - LO <abc@something.com>
To: abc@something.com
Subject: File processed - Price_Change_10-27-15 07-08-44
MIME-VERSION: 1.0
CONTENT-TYPE: MULTIPART/MIXED;name="Price_Change_10-27-15.csv"
CONTENT-DISPOSITION: ATTACHMENT;
FILENAME="Price_Change_10-27-15 07-08-44.csv"
```

Note: I have also tried using SMTP and still does not work

Here is the sample of the mail i receive on running this code.

[image]

Comment: What's in that 5k you show? Are you actually using the cards above from your COBOL program? Where did you put the data? Please explain, much more clearly. Also, why in the COBOL program? The usual way would be to set an RC, and an email step dependent on the value. What do you mean you tried SMTP? What did you try before your tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are generating the text of the email from within your Cobol program, which it sounds like, you would need to append another section, specify the Content-Type and Content-Disposition, filename and encoding, and then follow it with the properly encoded data, similar to this:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; name="Price_Change_10-27-15 07-08-44"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Price_Change_10-27-15 07-08-44"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDfrfoCnAEAAEcGAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAAC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
... and so on ...
```

I did notice that you had the content of those tags in upper case, that might be a problem.  RFC1341 specifies those as "multipart/mixed" and "attachment" and so on.  It is possible that your lack of mixed case is messing you up.

```
CONTENT-TYPE: MULTIPART/MIXED;name="Price_Change_10-27-15.csv"
CONTENT-DISPOSITION: ATTACHMENT;
FILENAME
```

Even easier than generating your own, have you looked into the excellent XMITIP package by Lyonel B. Dyck, it manages all that for you and you write a few config arms to control it, and you can easily call it from a Cobol program just like any other Rexx.  Or you could add it to the end of your job stream as a separate step and make the task really easy.